# Vue не видит значение input text, которое передал JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, vue.js

Есть 3 ползунка, значения которых передаются в 3 input text при помощи JQuery.
Vue выполняет роль калькулятора(складывает переданные значения).Однако он не видит значения, которые JQuery передал в поля ввода. **Как сделать так, чтобы Vue видел эти значения и реагировал на их изменения?(когда я заполняю эти поля вручную - всё работает)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" step="1" min="4" max="20" class="calculator-block__range calculator-block_range_1" name="my_range" data-grid="true" data-force-edges="true" data-min="4" data-max="20" data-step="1" data-values="1, 8.25, 15.5, 22.75, 30">
<!--/.Первый ползунок -->
<input type="text" @input="price()" v-model="pr1" class="calculator-block__result-x">
<!--/.Первое текстовое поле с результатом -->
<!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<input type="text" step="1" min="4" max="20" class="calculator-block__range calculator-block_range_2" name="my_range" data-grid="true" data-force-edges="true" data-min="4" data-max="20" data-step="1" data-values="1, 8.25, 15.5, 22.75, 30">
<!--/.Второй ползунок -->
<input type="text" @input="price()" v-model="pr2" class="calculator-block__result-y">
<!--/.Второе текстовое поле с результатом -->
<!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<input type="text" step="1" min="4" max="20" class="calculator-block__range calculator-block_range_3" name="my_range" data-grid="true" data-force-edges="true" data-min="4" data-max="20" data-step="1" data-values="1, 8.25, 15.5, 22.75, 30">
<!--/.Третий ползунок -->
<input type="text" @input="price()" v-model="pr3" class="calculator-block__result-z">
<!--/.Третье текстовое поле с результатом -->
<!-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!--/.Результат вычислений(Vue JS) -->
<span class="calculator-block__result">{{val}}</span>
```

**JQuery**

```
    var $range1 = $(".calculator-block_range_1"),
        $range2 = $(".calculator-block_range_2"),
        $range3 = $(".calculator-block_range_3"),
        $result1 = $(".calculator-block__result-x"),
        $result2 = $(".calculator-block__result-y"),
        $result3 = $(".calculator-block__result-z");

    var track1 = function (data) {
        $result1.val(+data.from);
    };

    var track2 = function (data) {
        $result2.val(+data.from);
    };

    var track3 = function (data) {
        $result3.val(+data.from);
    };

    $(".calculator-block_range_1").ionRangeSlider({ 
        onStart: track1,
        onChange: track1,
        onFinish: track1,
        onUpdate: track1               
    });

    $(".calculator-block_range_2").ionRangeSlider({ 
        onStart: track2,
        onChange: track2,
        onFinish: track2,
        onUpdate: track2               
    });

    $(".calculator-block_range_3").ionRangeSlider({ 
        onStart: track3,
        onChange: track3,
        onFinish: track3,
        onUpdate: track3               
    });
```

**Vue JS**

```
  var app = new Vue({
  el: '.wrapper',
  data: {
      val: 1000,
      pr1: 10,
      pr2: 2,
      pr3: 5
  },
  computed: {
      price(){
         return this.val = +this.pr1 + +this.pr2+ +this.pr3 ;
      }
  }
});
```

**Как это выглядит**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переменная `val` избыточна. Удалите присвоение `this.val` и выводите `price`. Так же удалите `@input=price()`. И Jquery тоже удалите

Comment: jQuery удалить никак нельзя, потому что именно он выводит значения ползунков в input text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь нужно задействовать механизм доступа черех `ref`.

Подробнее можно найти в документации [Доступ к экземплярам дочерних компонентов и элементов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Примерная реализация компонента:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input id="id" ref="price" v-model="price">
    <button @click="calc">calculate</button>
    <div>
      Price: {{price}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  mounted(){
    // эмулируем изменение через JQUERY
    setTimeout(function(){
      var input = document.getElementById('id');
      input.value = 500;
    }, 1000);
  },
  data(){
    return {
      price: 0
    }
  },
  methods:{
    calc(){
      console.log(this.$refs['price'].value);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```